# Get scrollTop() as a Percentage of Element height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen *many* questions along these lines and none of them seem to work in my situation because they all seem to rely on the page being scrolled.

This is NOT the case. The page is NEVER scrolled. I have tried lots of solutions and I am now thoroughly confused.

I have an absolutely positioned DIV element (The parent) with scrolling disabled.
I have an absolutely positioned child element inside it that has scrolling enabled and plenty of content to ensure that scrolling will take place.

I need to get the scrollTop() of that child element as a percentage.

I have tried many things along these lines:

```
var sPcent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
```

but I cannot for the life of me work out how to make this work in my case. The document height seems to have nothing to do with the elements I am working with. It would seem that

```
child.height() / child.scrollTop()
```

should work, but it does not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the maximum scrollable height of an element with `(elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.outerHeight())`.

Divide this by `100` and use the result to divide your element's `scrollTop()`.

```
var sPcent = $('#child').scrollTop() / (($('#child')[0].scrollHeight - $('#child').outerHeight()) / 100);
```

```js
var sPcent = 0;


$('#child').on('scroll',function(){
  sPcent = $('#child').scrollTop() / (($('#child')[0].scrollHeight - $('#child').outerHeight()) / 100);
  console.log(sPcent);
});
```

```css
#parent{
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#child{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work. The Page does not scroll. The Parent does not scroll. Only the child element scrolls its content. I need that scroll as a percentage of the child height. Using $(window).height() seems entirely irrelevant and makes for some interesting, and entirely wrong, results.

Comment: @MaxVK I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I updated my answer.